# Is it possible to subscribe one control to the same event handler multiple times?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, event-handling

I would like to know if I bind the `TextChanged` event handler to a `TextBox` control, then how can I ensure that won't be allowed to bind this event handler again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can't ensure that.** You would theoretically be allowed to bind the same event handler to a textbox (or other control) more than once. The only thing that events allow you to do is add a handler and remove a handler—there's no additional means provided to check for existing subscribers. If you don't believe me, Jon Skeet provides [the authoritative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232863/c-event-handlers/232865#232865) here, and in [his article on events](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx).

If you need to ensure that you don't accidentally subscribe a control to the same event twice, you'll need to keep track of it yourself. Honestly, you should never end up in a situation where you don't know what event handlers are subscribed. Not only does this reflect sloppy design, but it probably also means that you aren't taking care to *remove* your event handlers when they are no longer necessary.

A possible solution is provided in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367523/how-to-ensure-an-event-is-only-subscribed-to-once), but I caution you from using something like this blindly. As others have argued, this code is something of an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind it programatically as many times as you'd like. If you want to prevent this you can use a List<object> to keep references in, for example:

```
   
   private List gotRefs = new List();
   public void MyMethod()
   {
      if (!gotRefs.Contains(txtTextBox1)) {
        txtTextBox1.TextChanged += txtTextBox1_TextChanged;
        gotRefs.Add(txtTextBox1);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use a hack.

- You can make textbox private to your class to ensure, that only your single class is able to access the text box and add handlers to it.

```
private TextBox txtChanging;
```

- Then, in your class, you can create a custom event like textBoxTextChanged

```
public event Action TextBoxTextChanged;
```

- Create a standart method OnTextBoxTextChanged

```
private OnTextBoxChanged( object sender, EventArgs args )
{
    if( TextBoxTextChanged != null )
        TextBoxTextChanged();
}
```

- Bind this OnTextBoxChangedMethod to TextChanged event of the TextBox

```
txtChanging.TextChanged += OnTextBoxChanged;
```

- Ensure that NO OTHER METHOD is bound to TextChanged event of the text box
- Bound all your main payload text changed handlers to your new custom event instead of text box textchanged event directly

```
TextBoxTextChanged += txtChanged_TextChnaged;
```

- All that paperwork is because events actually provide a lot of information, but only to the methods **inside the class where they are defined**.
- You can check bound delegates with

```
TextBoxTextChanged.GetInvocationList()
```

and their count with

```
TextBoxTextChanged.GetInvocationList().Count() //(C# 4.0/LINQ)
```

or just count them through foreach.